# RoboCopy in script is not working

Tags: windows, batch-file, robocopy

My script below is quite straight forward but I am unable to make the `robocopy` work.

```
@echo off & setlocal

set remotePath=E:\RemotePath\
set s=001 002 003

set path=Y:\P25_Ladybug\RENDER\Comp\LB003\Sc001\

for %%a in (%s%) DO (

        robocopy "%path%%%a%" "%remotePath%%%a%" /XD *

        )

pause
```

If I change the remotepath (`"%remotePath%%%a%"`) to simple one like `Desktop` then it will work:

```
robocopy "%path%%%a%" Desktop /XD *
```

Any advice on what is wrong with mine?

The cmd results looks like

```
Y:\P25_Ladybug\RENDER\Comp\LB003\Sc001\001remotePath%\*.*
            *
            *.* /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30 Y:\P25_Ladybug\RENDER\Comp\LB003\Sc00
1\002remotePath%\*.*
            *
            *.* /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30 Y:\P25_Ladybug\RENDER\Comp\LB003\Sc00
1\003remotePath%\*.*
            *
            *.* /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30 Press any key to continue . . .
```

Thanks

Comment: Try adding `echo` before the `robocopy` command and check the expansion result. I bet the last `%` should be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax for a loop variable is `%%a` without the trailing `%`. In your code that hanging `%` was expecting a variable name after it and got nothing skipping everything until the required closing `%` effectively stripping the opening `%` from the `%remotePath%` variable, that's why the path was incorrect.

This is the correct syntax:

```
robocopy "%path%%%a" "%remotePath%%%a" /XD *
```